# C# SendKeys works except in one window?

Tags: c#, winforms, input, keyboard

I am trying to simulate a keypress, but when I'm trying to use it in a game it dosent detect it. It works on Google and Visuel Studio, it even works in the game chat where I used `SendKeys.Send("E")`.
So why do the game not detect it?

I am playing in windowed fullscreen, if thats useful info.

Methods I have tried

- `SendKeys.Send("E");`
- `SendKeys.SendWait("{E}");`
- `PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0100, Keys.E, IntPtr.Zero);`

Answer (score 0):

> SendKeys.SendWait()

Worked perfectly for me when i did a bot for an online flash game. Maybe the game where you try to use it is a bit more "advanced" and blocks This kind of virtual keyboard input to prevent something like cheating.